# How to change popup background color in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I've created this popup menu in my project and I'm trying to change the the background color of the popup menu but not really sure how I ca change it so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

```
                      ? PopupMenuButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.more_vert,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          onSelected: selectedOption,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return Popup.choises.map((String value) {
                              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value),
                              );
                            }).toList();
                          })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
PopupMenuButton(
           color: Colors.white,
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.more_vert,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              onSelected: selectedOption,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return Popup.choises.map((String value) {
                                  return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: value,
                                    child: Text(value),
                                  );
                                }).toList();
                              })
```

Comment: Hi, it work and thank you for this. by any chance do you also know how I can make the popup menu edge to be little bit round in each corner. Thanks

Comment: use  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),

Comment: Hi can you help me with one too pls,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852162/how-do-i-change-popup-menu-selected-menu-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the color parameter to PopupMenuButton and it will work.

```
///example
PopupMenuButton(
color:Colors.red,
/// other parameters/options
)
```

Comment: Hi, it work and thank you for this. by any chance do you also know how I can make the popup menu edge to be little bit round in each corner. Thanks

Comment: use the shape parameter to do it.

Comment: Hi can you help me with one too pls,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852162/how-do-i-change-popup-menu-selected-menu-in-flutter

Comment: I don't see any specific option for that in the API documentation. There is one solution that can work out for you is that as PopupMenuItem's child parameter takes a widget. You can pass your customized widget there with background color or splash color., For example, you can wrap your widget into Container and set a background color or use a ListTile or InkWell to set up a background color/splash color(hover effect like CSS). Make sure you wrap InkWell into Material Widget to work according to your expectations. I hope it helps you to achieve your expected results.